# Creating an image with a transparent background as on OLE object

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am wondering if it is possible in Access to create images to be stored in a table which have transparent backgrounds.  It seems to me that even if the image originally has a transparent backgound, upon uploading it into the table (as on OlE image) it then takes on a bitmap format which unfortunately cant be transposed.  Does anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: Does your applications uses back-end database server?
I guess most of the DB designers will agree to save images as files rather than loading into the Database which will increase the DB size and decrease the performance. Access image viewer cannot handle pictures from internet location but you can use web-browser control to show the images? or you have to use third-party image viewers.

Comment: Simply, i need to store images in a table in my database (back end database) and i need them to have transparency.  I don't think it is possible.